# How to test to two different WebServices using groovy in soapui and compare there responses using groovy scripts

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I have a situation where a need to compare two Soap responses  of two different web services which share the same Soap request,

Comment: Well you need to provide the data you are trying to compare. Also, mention what have you tried so far.

Comment: See if this is helpful - https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Groovy-XML-Comparison-Dynamic-XML-Attributes-are-not-ignored/m-p/139489#U139489

Answer (score 0):

in a simple way in groovy like this:

```
def res1 = context.getTestCase().getTestStepByName('The NAME OF SERVICE CALL STEP1').getPropertyValue('Response')
def res2 = context.getTestCase().getTestStepByName('The NAME OF SERVICE CALL STEP2').getPropertyValue('Response')

//reformat xmls to avoid space difference and to remove comments (groovy parser do this)
def xmlParser = new XmlParser()

res1 =  XmlUtil.serialize( xmlParser.parseText(res1) )
res2 =  XmlUtil.serialize( xmlParser.parseText(res2) )

assert res1==res2
```

but to compare xmls is not so simple because namespace prefixes, order of elements,... could be different.

in this case you can write some functions to `normalize` xml after arsing but before serializing...